# Populate Jquery Combobox in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, combobox

I am new in Jquery and in MVC 3.

I am trying to create a very simple example.

I have a jquery combobox and during page load I want to populate it with some data.

So here is the code:

**Client**

```
$(function () {
       $("#combobox").combobox({
        //    initialValues: ['array', 'of', 'values'],
           source: function (request, response) {
               if (!request.term.length) {
                   response(_self.options.initialValues);
               } else {
                   if (typeof _self.options.source === "function") {
                       _self.options.source(request, response);
                   } else if (typeof _self.options.source === "string") {

                       $.ajax({
                           url: "/dropdown/GetList",
                           //data: request,
                           dataType: "json"
                           //success: function (data, status) {
                             //  response(data);
                           //},
                           //error: function () {
                            //   response([]);
                          // }
                       });



                   }
               }
           }

        });
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
          //  $("#combobox").toggle();
        });
    });


**Function in Controller**
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetList()
        {
            try
            {
                Employee objName = new Employee();
                objName.Name = "Test";
                List<Employee> objectList = new List<Employee>();
                objectList.Add(objName);
                return Json(new { Records = objectList, TotalRecordCount = 1 });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

I have put a breakpoint in the server side function but it never reaches there.
  I will really appreciate your help!

Thanks in advanced,
V

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your url. Try `dropdown/GetList` this should work.

Also give [this article](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-an-action-from-javascript-or-jquery-in-mvc-3-razor/) a read.

Here is a simple example I could come up with,

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    string test = "Hello World";
    return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Web Api Code**

```
public string Test()
{
    string test = "Hello World";
    return test;
}
```

**Jquery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/Test",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The Url and actioname are both correct .However, I will read the article you have just recommended

Comment: Yes , I have tried that and its working . The problem is how to bind it to the combo box.

Comment: Hello world appears in the Console.Log , therefore , it reaches the server .

Answer (score 0):

I used to load data in dropdown/combobox by the below method. Please make sure the URL specified is correct. It will call the ActionResult which you specified in the URL of the 'Controller' and in the ActionResult return Json to load the data.

**Script**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dropDownOptions = null;
    function GetdropDownData(sender, args) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/GetCountries",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                dropDownOptions = data;

            }
        });
    }

  </script>
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult GetCountries()
    {
        return Json(CountryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }


public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList
    {
        get
        {
            // load data here
            return type;
        }
    }
```